# Not clicking but selenuim

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

For a time I've been using this site [link](https://tradingeconomics.com/spx:ind).
I used to click on the but "Show More", and scrape.
Now they may change it and it won't click the but any more.
Codes that I already tried.

```
time.sleep(4) 
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div/div[7]/div[1]/div/div/span").click()

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div/div[7]/div[1]/div/div/span")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Comment: Your second part of code i.e. clicking using `JS` is perfectly working fine, it clicks on `Show More` button. What issue are you facing with it? What error do you see on the console?

Comment: It won't click, it's wait the 30 sec and bring back error that the element is not in the html

Comment: Strange I used your same code and it works. Anyway, using absolute XPath is a bad idea. Try this XPath expression which is more reliable and see if it works `//span[text()='Show More']`

Comment: Where I can learn how to write XPath like yours?

Comment: Below are the 2 links where you can find about writing absolute XPATH expressions. There are a lot more blogs like these on google. Refer these 2 to start with. https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/complete-guide-for-using-xpath-in-selenium-with-examples/    https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below working code, which clicks on <kbd>Show More</kbd> button:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://tradingeconomics.com/spx:ind')
driver.maximize_window()

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Show More']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```